# YCbCr to RGB conversion with given matrix

Tags: matrices

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Y \\ Cb \\ Cr
\end{pmatrix}
 =
\mathrm{Round}
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
0.2126\times\frac{219}{255} &
0.7152\times\frac{219}{255} &
0.0722\times\frac{219}{255} \\
-\frac{0.2126}{1.8556}\times\frac{224}{255} &
-\frac{0.7152}{1.8556}\times\frac{224}{255} &
0.5\times\frac{224}{255} \\
0.5\times\frac{224}{255} &
-\frac{0.7152}{1.5748}\times\frac{224}{255} &
-\frac{0.0722}{1.5748}\times\frac{224}{255} 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
R \\ G \\ B
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
16 \\ 128 \\ 128
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is it possible to derive formula from above matrix that converts YCbCr to RGB? I am newbie to maths.

I have YCbCr value already available, I want to convert it to RGB.

Comment: You should be able to translate the formulae in the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) to matrix format...

Comment: I interpreted his question as asking how to invert that transformation in his linked equation; hence the wiki entry containing the YCbCr▶RGB conversion, which can be translated to a matrix-vector format if one wishes. As it stands, I don't know how to invert something that has the rounding function in it. :)

Comment: @J.M.: You're right, I misread the question. I shouldn't be browsing this site late at night... :-/

Comment: The round function just round up or down the number? if that is the case, just take it out and then it not hard to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a linear matrix. All you need is to do a complete reverse. (This will not take into the account Round part)

So let:

```
C - you YCbCr matrix
M - be your transformation matrix (the one with a lot of math inside)
V - your [16 128 128]' vector
R - your RBG matrix
```

So your starting formula is:

```
C = round( M * R ) + V
```

So in reverse this will be

```
R = M^(-1) * (C - V)
```